# Keep MySQL database in sync with polled data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

I have an interesting situation where I am constantly polling data from a server. I have no control over the content it provides, so I just have to deal with what it gives me.

I am logging some of the information it provides, and storing it in a MySQL database. This isn't really a problem, however, my problem is how to efficiently keep the data in sync with the database.

For example, at one point I could have 3 IDs 1001, 1002, 1003. I can insert these into the database just fine, however what if I now have 1001, and 1003. What would be the most efficient way to update the database to reflect this? Basically, I only know what I have NOW, and I have no way to know what has changed without calculating that myself in PHP.

I figure I can SELECT, find the difference, then issue DELETEs/INSERTs for lost/added IDs. Or perhaps a DELETE NOT IN () then an INSERT.. but as this script runs all the time I am afraid this wouldn't be very efficient.

Another thought I had was simple making one row per "player" with a CSV separated list of the IDs. Each iteration I could UPDATE the row for that player, rather than SELECT/DELETE/INSERT.

Has anyone come across a similar problem and found a good solution or has some insight? I would greatly appreciate it! I am using PHP.

Comment: If you're looking to replace the existing data with the latest received from the server, why not clear everything that's currently stored and then insert that which has been received?

Comment: Delete all rows from one player, and insert the current data? How efficient would this be, also considering I need to access this information from other scripts. At pretty much all times one player would have no rows, and that would be invalid.

Comment: Do both operations (DELETE, then INSERT) within a transaction: other sessions would then perceive it to be atomic.

Comment: Hm. I had never considered transactions. How do you think this compares in efficiency to having PHP SELECT, compare data, and DELETE/INSERT as necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try `REPLACE INTO` if I get what you're asking.

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-replace.aspx

If the record which you want to insert does not exist, the MySQL REPLACE inserts a new record.

If the record which you want to insert already exists, MySQL REPLACE deletes the old record first and then insert a new record.

The will keep you from Selecting, Deleting and insterting. This handles that.

Comment: I don't necessarily need to REPLACE the information that already exists. I am more concerned with efficiently removing rows that no longer exist in my source data and inserting new rows.

Comment: Oh, sorry let me explain better. I do not need to delete the current rows unless they do not exist in my source data anymore. Replace isn't appropriate here, as it would replace with the same information.

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford to truncate the entire table and load it over again, you could do it.

OR

Create a temp table with the new data loaded in it

join the original table with the temp table and delete rows that don't exist in the temp table

OR

Using a programming language, identify ids that no longer need to exist in the original table and delete them